# entity framework multiple cascade paths error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

What I've done so far to achieve what I want using Entity Framework is something like this:

```
// User.cs
public class User {
  public Guid ID { get; set; } // column: user_id
  public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
// Event.cs
public class Event {
  public Guid ID { get; set; } // column: event_id
  public virtual Guid UserID { get; set; } // column: event_userid
  public virtual ICollection<User> Guests { get; set; }
}
// MyAppContext.cs
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb) {
  mb.Entity<User>()
    .HasKey(u => u.ID)
    .HasMany(u => u.Events)
    .WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserID);

  mb.Entity<Event>()
    .HasKey(e => e.ID)
    .HasMany(e => e.Guests)
    .WithMany();
}
...
```

I was expecting the database structure to be as follows:

```
TABLE: user
user_id uniqueidentifier not null primary key

TABLE: event
event_id uniqueidentifier not null primary key
event_userid uniqueidentifier not null foreign key references user(user_id)

TABLE: event_guests
event_id uniqueidentifier not null
user_id uniqueidentifier not null
```

I have a feeling that the fluent API I'm using above is not going to give the expected database structure and also, I get the following exception that I've no clue how to fix:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_xxx' on table 'event_guests'
may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO
ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

I'm new to entity framework, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your configurations with a single many to many configuration.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Events)
            .WithMany(b=> b.Guests)
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                x.MapRightKey("EventId");
                x.ToTable("EventGuests");
            });
```

Comment: In some other post was suggested to try this: modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>(); I did and it works fine now. Thanks.